# Special character removal under GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For my make file I use a variable named VERSION_NUMBER which is passed from a build environment in the following form:

VERSION_NUMBER='#258'

Now, I wish to extract the number 258 from this string under make, but I'm unable to do so due to the special character '#'.

I've tried the following and it works (for now assume that the variable is locally defined in the makefile and not passed from the build environment):

```
VERSION_NUMBER:='\#258'

empty:=
quote:='
space:= $(empty) $(empty)
pound:=\#

extract:= $(subst $(quote),$(empty),$(VERSION_NUMBER))
$(info $$extract is [${extract}]) # Debug print

extract:= $(subst $(pound),$(empty),$(extract))
$(info $$extract is [${extract}]) # Debug print
```

This prints out the following:

```
$extract is [#258]
$extract is [258]
```

The problem however is that here I'm using the VERSION_NUMBER as **'\#258'** instead of **'#258'** and unfortunately I can't get it to work in any other way.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is your problem. It seems you already have a working solution. Anyway if you want `make` not to interpret a `#` symbol, escaping it with a backslash is the correct solution so I wouldn't search for anything else.

Comment: The problem is that the build system supplies a string with and un-escaped `#`. However, the solution I presented works with an escaped `#`. So the question becomes, if is it possible at all, to modify the un-escaped input string (`'#258'`) into an escaped one (`'\#258'`) within the makefile?

Comment: Now you want to add the backslash ? Why add it ? See my answer, the behavior will be the same from an external input than from a variable declared within the Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash is here to escape the `#` symbol, so as it's not interpreted by `make`. I don't see where's your problem, because in your case it will not appear in your string.

Anyway you already hold the solution, which works for a var declared in your Makefile as well as for a var coming from the call to `make`. The only difference is that inside your Makefile you have to escape the `#` character.

Take this simple Makefile :

```
VERSION_NUMBER:='\#258'
pattern:=\#

# Remove the quotes and the hash symbol
PARSED_VERSION_NUMBER = $(subst ',,$(subst $(pattern),,$(VERSION_NUMBER)))

all: 
    @echo Version number is $(VERSION_NUMBER)
    @echo Parsed version number is $(PARSED_VERSION_NUMBER)
```

If you call it with `make all` you will have this output :

> Version number is '#258'
>
> Parsed version number is 258

See how the backslash disappeared.

Now if you call it with `make all VERSION_NUMBER='#286'` you will have this output :

> Version number is '#286'
>
> Parsed version number is 286

As you can see it's exactly the same behavior.

Comment: Excuse my naivety, but would it also work if I send the following command: `make all VERSION_NUMBER='#286'`

Comment: What you are saying is absolutely right. Perhaps I'm not framing my question correctly

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot the `'` and `#` symbols.   I added it, so yes it works.

Comment: That's what this site is for :-)